# Database Encryption Methods in SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to setup the data encryption on SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition at database level. I already tried TDE but it is not available in Standard edition.

What can be the most efficient way of data encryption at database level in SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition?

Comment: [Options for Data Encryption in SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50355/options-for-data-encryption-in-sql-server-2008-r2-standard-edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Standard Edition, there are several things you can do to encrypt data

- EFS is a windows feature that can be used to encrypt the contents of files or folders using a certificate installed on the server. Be sure to test this on a non production system before impelementing and that the certificate is safely backed up.
- Column level encryption can be implemented to protect the data
- You can use Bitlocker to encrypt drives on your server to prevent low level attacks or data theft.

With 2008 R2 Enterprise, there are some additional methods to address encryption

- TDE is one you already mentioned, so I'm sure you are familiar with this option
- EKM stands for Extensible Key Management system and it can be an expansion card or separate hardware with a high speed interface that offloads the storage of keys and encryption and decryption functions. It can be managed by a separate team that the DBA for effective separation of duties.